# Use @jest-environment jsdom and @jest-environment node both in the same project [Jest-ReactJS]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, ts-jest

We are using "Jest with React Testing Library" for unit testing in our project. In the same project we have some cases those needs "@jest-environment jsdom" and some cases needs @jest-environment node. How can we switch this in a Test Case file.

We have below jest.config.js file:

```
 /** @type {import('ts-jest/dist/types').InitialOptionsTsJest} */
    module.exports = {
      preset: 'ts-jest',
      testEnvironment: 'node'
    };
```

I have tried below approach, but it didn't work in my experience.

```
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */

test('use jsdom in this test file', () => {
  const element = document.createElement('div');
  expect(element).not.toBeNull();
});

/**
 * @jest-environment node
 */

test('do not use jsdom in this test file', () => {
  console.log(window); // this will fail as node doesn't have a window object
});
```